# How to properly clear the whole backstack ( without popping to the top element )?

Tags: android, fragment-backstack

Using android, I was wondering if it was a proper and clean way to clear the whole backstack?

I found many answers on SO for that but they all make me pop to the top element. What I need is just a simple way to clean the backstack in order to keep it clean after some advanced process deep into my fragments.

I don't need ( and I don't want ) to change my current fragment or **to start a new activity** ( for a perfomance purpose ). All I need is an empty backstack to avoid further troubles.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Afaik, you cannot just "clear it", you have to start a new activity with the intents flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

A proposition is to start your activity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` tag, or override the back button so people cannot navigate back

Comment: But restarting my activity would be to greedy in term of performance, I'm actually changing some parts of my app to avoid performance issue and restarting my app was a way for me to start again on clean bases after some long process. However being to needing in term of resources, I cannot do that anymore.

Comment: Just to see if I understood correctly: What you want is to remove all the fragments from the backstack but stay with your current Fragment on the screen?

Comment: yes, that's exactly that.